# PHP preg_replace remove first HTML element in string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I would like to remove the entire first element of a html string (it is always a paragraph) in PHP.

my current approach  is using:

```
$passage = preg_replace('/.*?\b'.'</p>'.'\b/s', '', $passage, 1);
```

This doesn't work because of the special characters in `</p>`

I know that the following will remove everything from the string before the word 'one' appears

```
$passage = preg_replace('/.*?\b'.'one'.'\b/s', '', $passage, 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to escape '/' with a backslash if you're using it as a delimiter: So it's `<\/p>`

Edit: You should add a `^` to mark the start of the string.

Another solution: You can use other delimiters like `#`.

Full code `$passage = preg_replace('#^.*?</p>#is', '', $passage, 1);`

Comment: are you suggesting the following:    $passage = preg_replace('/.*?\b'.'<\/p>'.'\b/s', '', $passage, 1);    This runs fine but does not appear to change the variable in any way.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue? this is my exact code:<?
$passage = '<p>this should not display</p><p>this should display</p>';
 $passage = preg_replace('/^.*?\b'.'<\/p>'.'\b/s', '', $passage, 1);
echo $passage;
?>

Comment: Edited again: I would do it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regExp

`$passage = preg_replace('/^<p>\s*(.+?)\s*</p>$/is','$1', $passage, 1);`